How to force iOS Safari to recognize new URL
In the webapp a QR-code is generated, that represents an href URL with a matrix parameter, e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/pathtopage/page.html#/upload;uaid=8g7Vcewr89439BRF43nW8hbzrKTKh
This QR code is now scanned on an iPhone to open the URL in Safari. The problem is now when a new URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/pathtopage/page.html#/upload;uaid=9f03kljjfhjeo8uiiefw4GHJKkKKL
with a new uid param is generated and scanned again, Safari on iOS does not rcognize it if the tab from the first scan is still open.
There is a similar issue in the Apple developer forum.:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738411
We already tried also URLs like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/pathtopage/page.html#/upload?uid=9f03kljjfhjeo8uiiefw4GHJKkKKL
https://stackoverflow.com/pathtopage/page.html#/upload?uid=9f03kljjfhjeo8uiiefw4GHJKkKKL&TIMESTAMP=blub

How to get Safari to recognize the new URL?
